# Why is there a duplicate primary key error in my postgresql insert statement when there is no duplicate?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, primary-key

Note: After reading some comments, I updates my query to the following, which works. But perhaps there is a more concise solution.
This seems to do the trick...

```
insert into duplicates(contact_id_a, contact_id_b, ignore_duplicate, has_been_fetched, list_id, contact_a_name, contact_b_name) 
SELECT 32753, 42260, false, false, 567, (select data->>'firstname' as ca_firstname from contacts where contact_id = 32753),
(select data->>'firstname' as cb_firstname from contacts where contact_id = 42260) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM duplicates WHERE list_id = 567  
                  AND ((contact_id_a = 32753 and contact_id_b = 42260) OR (contact_id_a = 42260 and contact_id_b = 32753) ));
```

Why is my postgresql query raising this duplicate primary key error when there is no duplicate?

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "duplicates_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (contact_id_a, contact_id_b, list_id)=(32753, 42260, 567) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

The duplicates table is empty, so I would imagine the new row is unique.

Here is the query. It's pretty clear what I am doing, but in a nutshell, inserting a new row into the duplicates table containing name information from a second table called `contacts` only if there is not already a row in the duplicates table containing the specified contact_ids and list_id.

```
insert into duplicates(contact_id_a, contact_id_b, ignore_duplicate, has_been_fetched, list_id, contact_a_name, contact_b_name) 
SELECT 32753, 42260, false, false, 567, ca.data->>'firstname', cb.data->>'firstname'
from contacts c 
left join contacts ca on ca.list_id=567 and ca.contact_id = 32753 
left join contacts cb on cb.list_id=567 and cb.contact_id = 42260 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM duplicates WHERE list_id = 567  
                  AND ((contact_id_a = 32753 and contact_id_b = 42260) OR (contact_id_a = 42260 and contact_id_b = 32753) ));
```

Here is my primary key constraint...
[image]

Comment: Please run the query part of the `insert` and note here how many rows are returned.

Comment: Your query itself is returning duplicates on `(contact_id_a, contact_id_b, list_id)`.

Comment: Too many. Thank you for the tip. I see now that I had been pulling every row from the contacts table, when in fact I only want data from rows containing the specified contact_ids. I updated the select query as follows, and now get back two rows - one for each of the two specified contact_ids. Still, as you hinted at, the select statement must return only a single row.  All we need is for the whole query to insert a row into the duplicates table with some hardcoded values and the name values from the contacts table. Maybe I shouldn't be using a join at all, but rather nested statements.

Comment: SELECT 32753, 42260, false, false, 567, ca.data->>'firstname', cb.data->>'firstname'
from contacts c 
 left join contacts ca on ca.list_id=567 and ca.contact_id = 32753 
 left join contacts cb on cb.list_id=567 and cb.contact_id = 42260 
 where c.contact_id in (32753, 42260)

Comment: I found a solution that mostly works. Now how can I extend this to manage cb_firstname as well?

insert into duplicates(contact_id_a, contact_id_b, ignore_duplicate, has_been_fetched, list_id, contact_a_name) 
SELECT 32753, 42260, false, false, 567, ca_firstname 
from (select data->>'firstname' as ca_firstname from contacts where contact_id = 32753) as c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM duplicates WHERE list_id = 567  
      AND ((contact_id_a = 32753 and contact_id_b = 42260) OR (contact_id_a = 42260 and contact_id_b = 32753) ));

Comment: This seems to do the trick...

insert into duplicates(contact_id_a, contact_id_b, ignore_duplicate, has_been_fetched, list_id, contact_a_name, contact_b_name) 
SELECT 32753, 42260, false, false, 567, (select data->>'firstname' as ca_firstname from contacts where contact_id = 32753),
(select data->>'firstname' as cb_firstname from contacts where contact_id = 42260) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM duplicates WHERE list_id = 567  
      AND ((contact_id_a = 32753 and contact_id_b = 42260) OR (contact_id_a = 42260 and contact_id_b = 32753) ));

Comment: But perhaps there is a more concise solution?

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything try to dump you database so you can back to current state if any problem occurs, then try to REINDEX your database:

`REINDEX DATABASE <YOUR-DBNAME>;`

a vaccum may also be a good idea:
`vacuum(full, analyse, verbose);`

Answer (score 1):

The `select` is returning more than one row with the same key combo.

You need to fix your select query so it returns exactly one row per key combo.

You  *may* be able to get away with using `distinct`:

```
insert into duplicates (...) 
select distinct ...
```